# Glitchy, distorted flickering when my laptop screen has a very dark or black image on screen

Tags: laptop, lcd

Video Link of the problem: https://youtu.be/dikXS6dBK1w

Hello,

I've just recently got this problem that when the image on my screen has an overall dark image present the screen displays a very glitchy looking flickering, oddly looking similar to a VHS distortion effect. This problem isn't about the brightness of the backlight just the darkness level of the pixels on screen i guess?

It started happening when I was playing don't starve and come nighttime in-game i noticed the flickering. I backed out of the game and flickering was happening on steam as well so I assumed it was a steam issue. So I closed it to my desktop and no more flickering. Only when I restarted did I see that the Acer boot screen was also flickering like mad.

Does anyone know what might the problem be? This issue started two days ago. It might be due to something I did when I replaced the thermal paste, maybe a loose cable? but I opened my laptop like 1-2 months ago and it's been working perfectly since.

Laptop model: Acer V3-772G
CPU: Intel Core i7-4702MQ
GPU: Nvidia GTX 760M
RAM: 8GB DDR3
HDD: 1TB SATA

You can find more about the laptop here:

https://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Acer-Aspire-V3-772G-747A321-Notebook.93916.0.html

Thank you

Comment: If it happened during boot there is a hardware problem. You need to follow any warranty support if the system is under warranty, or consult a qualified local hardware technician.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have fixed the problem. I was avoiding opening my laptop but I did and made sure the cable for the graphics card and the monitor were secured properly in place. Maybe I didn't put them in properly the last time I opened it and it came loose over the weeks? Idk but it seems to be fixed for now.